# Unable to delete files from terminal

Tags: bash, awk

I have a folder that contains database backups, but i want to automate it using cron to delete old backups.

so i created the following script

```
#Get the current year
YEAR=$(date +'%Y')

#Get the current month
MONTH=$(date +'%m')

#Delete data from previous months
deleteOldData() { ls /root/copy/dbbackup/smpp_credits/ | awk -F "-" -v m="$MONTH" '$2 < m' | xargs -d "\n" rm -rf ;}

#Delete data from previous years ( if any )
deletePrevYearData() { ls /root/copy/dbbackup/smpp_credits/ | awk -F "-" -v y="$YEAR" '$3 < y' | xargs -d "\n" rm -rf ;}

deleteOldData

deletePrevYearData
```

Executing `ls /root/copy/dbbackup/smpp_credits/ | awk -F "-" -v m="$MONTH" '$2 < m'` in the terminal works as expected, (it lists the required files).
but upon appending `| xargs -d "\n" rm -rf` the code runs and returns without any output, and checking the directory reveals that the files are still there. By the way, this code is stored and executed from a .sh file

Comment: See [Why you shouldn't parse the output of `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs). The best practice here is to tell `find` to filter for the date range you want and directly call `rm` itself.

Comment: Also, `"\n"` is entirely different from `$'\n'`; only the latter is bash syntax for a single newline-literal character.

Comment: (Also, names can contain literal newlines, so unknown/arbitrary names can't be safely separated with newlines; how different tools will deal with the name of the directory created by `mkdir $'/tmp/\n/etc/passwd\n/hi'` will differ, but the set that will generate `/etc/passwd` as a separate line of output is nonzero).

Comment: ...also, by "a .sh file", do you mean a file executed with `sh`? `sh` is not bash -- the bash tag should be used only for questions about code run with `/bin/bash`, not `/bin/sh`.

Answer (score 1):

Parsing `ls` output is widely considered to be a bad idea. I would try a find command, which should be cleaner.

`find /root/copy/dbbackup/smpp_credits/ -maxdepth 1 -mtime +365 -exec rm -rf {} \;`

from [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/413529/delete-files-older-than-one-year-on-linux). You can use `-mtime +30` for files that are older than one month.

Comment: As I read it, the OP is looking to prune data that precedes the beginning of the current month, as opposed to data that's a year old.

Comment: BTW, `-exec rm -rf {} \;` is much slower than `-exec rm -rf {} +`, as the former invokes a separate copy of `rm` for each file; both are compliant with POSIX `find` since the 2008 revision of the standard. And `rm -rf --` will ensure that filenames starting with dashes are read as names, not as options (though granted, that shouldn't happen when `find` is passed a specific path to search from and not, say, given a wildcard that could expand to include a name that starts with a dash).

Answer (score 1):

Assuming GNU `find` and `date`, `-newermt` can be used to compare a file's modification time against a specific date given as an argument:

```
delete_older_than_date="$(date +'%Y-%m-01')"
find /root/copy/dbbackup/smpp_credits \
  -maxdepth 1 \
  -type f \
  '!' -newermt "$delete_older_than_date" \
  -exec rm -rf -- '{}' +
```